# Nexus 10 on rc-proposed won't boot

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, nexus-10

I have a nexus10 with ubuntu-dualboot. I want to install from the rc-proposed (manta) channel, but the latest versions (273,274) won't boot. It gets stuck on a boot loop around the Google logo.

The only way out is to use fastboot an install CM recovery, and use that to return to Android.

What can/should I do to fix it?

Comment: I'm assuming rc-proposed is still active for nexus 10, because I received and installed version 275 now, but I still can't boot it! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The images for the N10 have not been given too much attention due to Canonical having 3 official headsets out to support. Once a company starts making a tablet I'm sure they will give tablets more love.